# How I can replace customized /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file, when build Elastic Beanstalk from Docker File

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Dear network please take a look on following questions.

**ENVIRONMENT:**
*AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EBS)* (Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.4.12)

**SITUATION:**
I am running *AWS EBS* from Docker Platform and using Docker File to run the container. After deployment I need to replace nginx.conf file with my updated nginx.conf,

**ACTIONS:**
Trying to use in DockerFile `ADD https://my-scripts.s3.amazonaws.com/nginx.conf /etc/nginx` command, but after deployment the file isn't replacing the original file.

**RESULT:**
Seems the reason is, that nginx installing in container after Docker File process and probably to have custom nginx.conf I need to use on of the [aws platform
custom hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platform-hooks.html).

**QUESTIONS:**

- Am I in the right direction regarding custom hooks, or there are
  better ways to solve it?
- How platform custom hooks could be used for this case to build EBS:
  Should I just add hooks `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/postdeploy`
  EX: `ADD s3://my_custom_hook_script /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/postdeploy.`?
- As a solution just make war/zip archive with DockerFile and .platform/nginx/nginx.conf and deploy war/zip instead of DockerFile only. That replaced /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and not need to restart nginx. COuld be this meaningfull solution ?

**NOTE:**
When I was building *AWS EBS* from war file for my other service, I just added the `.platform/nginx/nginx.conf` under the root of project and after building war keep that folder in the same level as the generated project jar, which replace with custom `nginx.conf` without restarting **nginx service**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you already looked at this section in the docs for extending the nginx configuration? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html

Comment: @jordanm yes and for Amazon Linux 2 now the nginx.conf should in folder .platform/nginx/nginx.conf when using amazoncorreto 11 AL2. Only what I am thinking that just make war add there my dockerfile and .platform/nginx/nginx.conf and deploy war instead of DockerFile that will replace. But maybe there is better solutiin